# Shortest (undirected) path constrained to a sub-set of nodes

Tags: reference-request, set-covering, hamiltonian-path

I expect this to be an NP-complete problem, as it may reduce to the Hamiltonian Path problem.

Anyway, I was wondering whether there exists some study and (aproximated) solutions for this particular problem.

Formaly, for an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$, a source node $s$ and a subset $S\subseteq V$. Find the shortest path starting from $s$ and passing through as many as possible nodes in $S$.

EDIT 1: it may relate to the Spanning Tree as well. However, the Spanning Tree assume $G$ to be connected, which is not a necessary condition here.

EDIT 2: a possible solver might be to greedily choose a source-target pair of nodes and solve the problem described in [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/134798/shortest-path-including-all-nodes-in-a-subset).
Nevertheless, this is not the same problem. Also notice that it works on directed graphs. Not really efficient this my case so.

Comment: For the specific case where $S=\{v\}$, you can simply run the shortest path from the source to $v$. And a second time from $v$ to the sink.

Comment: the is no source nor sink.

Comment: you can add a dummy source and sink with 0 cost

Comment: the set $S$ may be disconnected, I don't think one dummy pair is enough..

Comment: You seem to be combining two objectives. Are you looking to find the maximum number of nodes that can be contained in one path from $s$ and then select from among the optimal paths the shortest one?